# java: run methods that are in a class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm very new to java, so the answer to this is bound to be pretty simple. :)

I'm trying to create a basic game of Tic-tac-toe using the console. I created a class called "Board," and in it, I created a method that will print out the tic-tac-toe board.

```
public void print() {
System.out.println("code");
}
```

How do I run this method from the `Main.java` code?

Comment: I think if you are very much new to JAVA, please first learn JAVA. Then try to develop a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Comment: @dualCore I edited my answer to better reflect your code, although you should post here the constructor of `Board`, to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this, inside the `Main` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board b = new Board();
    b.print();
}
```

After compiling the above code, you can run the `Main` class using the IDE of your choice, or the command line. The point is: for starting the execution of a program in Java, you define a `main` method in a class and from there, start calling the appropriate methods. In your example, I first instantiated the `Main` class and then invoked the requested method over an instance of the class.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that I understand what you're saying. Is there just a simple way to run a function (that's inside a class) from the main code?

Comment: For running a method in Java, first you need to instantiate an object of the class where that method resides. And the starting point of a Java program is a `main` method, which also resides in a class, and from there you do what you need. Give it a try, it's the best way to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Just to be clear - in Java we talk about "methods" and not "functions", to make the distinction that a method can not be executed without being part of a class or an instance of a class

Comment: I believe you should read a basic [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) to get your bearings

Comment: He said he has the print method in Board class, so first object of Board is required !

Comment: Ah, I see. I was typing in Board.print(); when I should have typed in the instance of the board class: play_area.print();